# Prove that in a topological space, empty intersection of a set and its boundary implies that the set is in the topology

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

As the title suggests, I would like to prove that in a topological space $(X,\tau)$ $$A\cap\partial A = \varnothing\implies A\in\tau$$ is true for $A\subset X$.

My attempt:

1. For every $x\in A,\,\exists T_x\in\tau$ with $x\in T_x$ and $T_x\subseteq A$.
   This follows from

$$\partial A := \{x \in X;\, \mathrm{for\ every\ } T\in\tau\mathrm{\ with\ } x\in T\mathrm{,\ } A\cap T \neq \varnothing \;\mathrm{and}\;(X\setminus A)\cap T \neq\varnothing\}$$

since if no such $T_x$ existed, then either

$$T_x\cap A\neq\varnothing\ \wedge\ T_x\cap\partial A\neq\varnothing\ \wedge\ T_x\cap(X\setminus \overline{A})=\varnothing$$

which is impossible by the definition of $\partial A$, or

$$T_x\cap A\neq\varnothing\ \wedge\ T_x\cap\partial A\neq\varnothing\ \wedge\ T_x\cap(X\setminus\overline{A} )\neq\varnothing$$

meaning $x\in\partial A$ which violates the assumption.

2. Since $T_x\subseteq A$ we have $\cup T_x\subseteq A$. Furthermore, for every $x\in A$ we have $x\in T_x$ so that $A\subseteq\cup T_x$. Thus $A = \cup T_x$, giving us $A\in\tau$ by definition.

Is this proof correct? and if so, is there a simpler way to prove the same thing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\partial A=\overline A\setminus \mathring A$ and $\mathring A\subseteq A\subseteq \overline A$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
A\subseteq \overline A &&\Rightarrow &&A\setminus \mathring A&\subseteq \overline A\setminus \mathring A\\
&&\Rightarrow &&A\setminus \mathring A = A\cap (A\setminus \mathring A)&\subseteq A\cap (\overline A\setminus \mathring A)= A\cap\partial A=\emptyset\\
\end{align*}
Therefore $A\setminus \mathring A=\emptyset$ and $A\subseteq \mathring A$, therefore $A=\mathring A\in \tau$.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Did you see any mistakes in my solution?

Comment: Your solution is a bit over complicated and it makes it hard to review, and therefore to know if there is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in A$; then $x\notin \partial A$, so $x\in A\setminus \partial A \subseteq \bar A\setminus \partial A $. Provided that $\bar A=\mathring A\cup \partial A$, we get $x\in (\mathring A\cup \partial A)\setminus \partial A=\mathring A$, hence $A\in \cal T$.